# Custom Filter not firing in angular1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have two fields in a digest: `genres` and `secondary_genre` which are integers.

I have a dropdown fields of genres which returns a value `(ng-model = query.genres)`

I have tried to create a custom function which will compare genre and secondary genre to query.genre and return if EITHER condition is met. Individually they work fine i.e with filter:{secondary_genre:query.genre) but for the OR condition I need a custom.

The custom filter I have written is called with

```
<li ng-repeat="film in listOfTitles | customGenreFilter:query.genre">
```

The filter is

```
.filter('customGenreFilter', function() {
    return function(data, query) {
        if (data) {
            return data.filter(data.genres == query || data.secondary_genre == query);
        }
        else {
            return [];
        }
    };
});
```

but it is throwing errors. How can I write this custom filter to return the item if the condition genres = query.genre OR secondary_genre = query.genre.

Comment: what does your `query.genre` object look like? Does it have `query.genre.genres`?

Comment: Integer only, no strings or fancy crap.. just a whole number from 1 to x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is not working because you are not using the `.filter()` method properly, the method require the argument to be a lambda function in which return whether the item should or not stay in the list. In order to fix your code you have to change the following line:

```
return data.filter(data.genres == query || data.secondary_genre == query);
```

To:

```
return data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.genre == query || item.secondary_genre == query
});
```

The following example implements a working version of your filter.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .component('app', {
    templateUrl: '/app.html',
    controller: App
  })
  .filter('customGenreFilter', CustomGenreFilter);

function App($scope) {
  $scope.query = {
    genre: ''
  };
  $scope.listOfTitles = [
    { title: 'test 1', genre: 'genre1' },
    { title: 'test 2', genre: 'genre2' },
  ];
}

function CustomGenreFilter() {
  return function(data, query) {
    if (query === '') return data;
    if (data) return data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.genre == query || item.secondary_genre == query
    });
    return [];
  };
}

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script id="/app.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <select ng-model="query.genre" ng-options="item as item for item in ['', 'genre1', 'genre2']">
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="film in listOfTitles | customGenreFilter:query.genre">
      {{ film.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<app />
```

Comment: Some very minor tweaking needed to fit in my code, but this solution 10/10, brilliant, thanks.